# Add const char and char in c

Tags: c, char, c-strings, string.h

I have a player `char player = x;` and want to overwrite a string `char string[30];` to contain `"Player" + player + "won"`. I tried

```
strcpy_s(string, "Player ");
strcat_s(string, player);
strcat_s(string, " won\n");
```

but obviously this doesn't work, because `char` is not compatible with `const char`

How can I do it instead?

Comment: "but obviously this doesn't work, because `char` is not compatible with `const char`". No, it's because `char` is not compatible with `char *`.

Comment: Also,  the `_s` versions should take the `sizeof string` as the second parameter.

Comment: You could do `strcat_s(string, 30, (char[2]){player});` or `char pl[2] = {player};` `strcat_s(string, 30, pl);`. (Possibly replace `30` with `sizeof string` if `string` is an array and not a pointer.)

Comment: And if it seems tempting, using `&player` as the final argument of the `strcpy_s` call would result in *undefined behavior* because the argument needs to point to a null-terminated string of `char`, and `&player` points to a single `char` with no null terminator after it. So don't do that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), your general purpose string-formatting stdlib function.

```
snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "Player %c won\n", player);
```

You can read all about the different `%` formatting directives available in the above link, but `%c` is the one you want for characters.

Comment: `snprintf` is advisable.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Good point. In this particular case, the string length is guaranteed (which is why I went `sprintf`), but you're absolutely right that `snprintf` is better advice to give someone for general use.

Answer (score 2):

- Using `char player` as an argument to `strcat_s` is not valid. It requires a, possibly `const`, `char*`.
- The second argument to the `_s` functions you use should be the number of elements in your `char` array.

Example:

```c
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[30];
    const char *player = "x";

    strcpy_s(string, sizeof string, "Player ");
    strcat_s(string, sizeof string, player);
    strcat_s(string, sizeof string, " won\n");
    
    puts(string); // prints "Player x won"
}
```

... but do not do this. It's a very inefficient way to build your final string. Instead do what Silvio Mayolo suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73323212/7582247).

Answer (score 0):

Using `sprintf` it can be done simply like

```
sprintf( string, "%s%c%s", "Player ", player, " won\n" );
```

or using `snprintf`

```
snprintf( string, sizeof( string ), "%s%c%s", "Player ", player, " won\n" );
```